# In Google Analytics for Android Apps, is a new session created if you send an event but not a screen view?

Tags: android, google-analytics

Say you have a service that listens for a GCM message and presents the user with a notification. At the time that the notification is created, we create a new GoogleAnalytics instance, make a new tracker, and send a GA event, but no screen view. Once the notification is tapped, then we send another event and a screen view depending on what was tapped.

Will GA count the case where we simply log an event but don't actually show an activity (and thus set no screen name) as a session?

An event is sent like this:

```
tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()....build());
```

But a screen view like below is not sent:

```
tracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

Comment: Have u got the answer of this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how much time has elapsed since the last hit was sent. If more time has elapsed than the session timeout period (30 minutes by default), it will be considered a new session regardless of whether or not a screenview hit is sent. If less time has elapsed than the session timeout period, it will be grouped in with the previous session.

Note, the session timeout period is configurable, and all sessions end at midnight in the timezone of your Google Analytics property.

For more info, read about [How a session is defined in Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en)